# add vertical line in jasperreports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, ireport

I am using *JasperReports* as a reporting tool for Web Application. (JSP + Servlets)

I have developed a Report named `Cust` which has Sub Report named `CustSub`. In sub report I want vertical line for some columns, so I have added a `line` of exact height of that `frame`. Height of `Bond`, `Frame` and vertical `line` is same.

[image]

So let me know if there is any better way of doing this?

**Update1**

This are the `styles` I have applied for alternate row color

```
<style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

and this is `Detail Band` (I have included only two textfields from code, so please don't consider `x="258"` of line,)

```
<detail>
<band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
    <frame>
        <reportElement uuid="aa7987da-d84a-4d11-b079-44005699151d" style="Row" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="1" y="0" width="555" height="18"/>

        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd/MM/yy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="8a0ce8e2-1beb-4300-81ea-f3422abef623" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="2" y="0" width="60" height="18"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRNDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>

        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="74be5885-f344-4451-a3a5-62213d3a3dd1" style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="120" y="0" width="68" height="18"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AMOUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>

    <line>
        <reportElement uuid="06d698e3-34c2-445a-8787-a54bd38a2121" style="Detail" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="258" y="0" width="1" height="18" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </line>

    </frame>
</band>
</detail>
```

Comment: Please do share your code.

Comment: @Bhushan Did you set the borders for *textFields* (*staticTexts*)? You should post your template

Comment: Try printing the report to see the real output. I think its just some sort of design view malfunction.

Comment: @onepotato ok I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Just drag line element from palette and drag the bottom middle point of that tile element to increase the size and then decrease the width by dragging left middle point.

Comment: I have done exactly same, but it is not giving expected output